# Code flaw for making 'Encript message' in Python

Tags: python

I am unable to correct my coding below and for some reason the code is not running. Please help me with the correction, and if possible please suggest better coding practice and help with shorter coding:

```
message = input ('Enter your message')

key = int (input('How many Characters should we shift(between 1 - 26)- '))

secret-message = ""
for char in message:

    if char.isalpha():
        #Get the character code and add the shift amount
        char_code = ord(char)
        chat_code += key
        #if upper case then compare to uppercase unicode
        if char.isupper():
            #if upper than Z substract 26
            if char_code > ord('Z'):
                char_code -= 26
            #if smaller than A add 26
            if char_code < ord('A'):
                char_cod += 26
        #Do the same for lower character
        else:
            if char_code > ord('z'):
                char_code -= 26
            if char_code < ord('a'):
                char_cod += 26
        #Convert From Code to letter and add to message
    secret-message = secret-message + chr(char_code)
    else:
        secret-message = secret-message + char
print (" Encripted :" , secret-message)
```

Comment: You are inconsistent with your variables: `char_code`, `chat_code`, `char_cod`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being inconsistent with the variables throughout your code, you are using `-` operator in `secret-message` because of which you are getting `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. After these corrections, your code is working:

```
message = input('Enter your message: ')

key = int(input('How many Characters should we shift(between 1 - 26)- '))

secret_message = ""

for char in message:
    if char.isalpha():
        #Get the character code and add the shift amount
        char_code = ord(char)
        char_code += key
        #if upper case then compare to uppercase unicode
        if char.isupper():            
            #if upper than Z substract 26
            if char_code > ord('Z'):
                char_code -= 26
            #if smaller than A add 26
            if char_code < ord('A'):
                char_code += 26
        #Do the same for lower character
        else:
            if char_code > ord('z'):
                char_code -= 26
            if char_code < ord('a'):
                char_code += 26
        #Convert From Code to letter and add to message                
        secret_message = secret_message + chr(char_code)
    else:
        secret_message = secret_message + char

print (" Encripted :" , secret_message)
```

Running it:

```
Enter your message: secret
How many Characters should we shift(between 1 - 26)- 5
 Encripted : xjhwjy
>>>
```

Now that your code is working and since you are interested in *better coding practice*, you may want to post the same at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for peer programmer code reviews.

Hope that helps.